# I am using Python script in Power BI. How can I format the x axis tick labels and titles for a multiple seaborn 'displot'

Tags: python, format

New on this and I could use some help. I am using the code below. The 3 lines at the end that supposed to format the x axis to currency and add gridlines doesn't seem to work but they are not returning an error neither. I would also like to change or hide the titles on the top of each subplot. Is it possible to hide the y axis?

```
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
    
    colors =["#FF0B04","#228800","#ffbb33"]
    sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
    hue_order = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.2, rc={"font.size":5,"axes.labelsize":12})
    
    g = sns.JointGrid()
    
    sns.displot(data=dataset, x="Profit",col= 'ClassificationChar', bins=50,hue= 'ClassificationChar', fill=True, stat="count", legend=False )
    
    ax = g.ax_joint
    
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '£{:,.0f}K'.format(x/1000)))
    ax.grid(b=True, which='major')
    ax.grid(b=True, which='minor')
    
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach and I came to the desired outcome by plotting every element separately.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

colors =["#FF0B04","#228800","#ffbb33"]
sns.set_palette(colors)

sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.2, rc={"font.size":5, "axes.labelsize":12})
sns.set_style("ticks", {"xtick.major.size":8,"ytick.major.size":8})
current_palette = sns.color_palette(colors)

x, y, z= dataset["OverallTotalScore%"], dataset["Profit"], dataset["ClassificationChar"]


f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots (1,3, figsize=(16, 6), sharey= True)
sns.despine(left=False, bottom=False, offset=0)

sns.histplot(x=y, hue=z, hue_order='A', stat="count", alpha = 1, palette = ['#228800'], kde=False, fill=True, legend=False, bins=50, ax=ax1)
sns.histplot(x=y, hue=z, hue_order='B', stat="count", alpha = 1, palette = ['#ffbb33'], kde=False, fill=True, legend=False, bins=50, ax=ax2)
sns.histplot(x=y, hue=z, hue_order='C', stat="count", alpha = 1, palette = ['#FF0B04'], kde=False, fill=True, legend=False, bins=50, ax=ax3)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '£{:,.0f}K'.format(x/1000)))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '£{:,.0f}K'.format(x/1000)))
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '£{:,.0f}K'.format(x/1000)))

ax1.grid(b=True, which='major')
ax1.grid(b=True, which='minor')
ax2.grid(b=True, which='major')
ax2.grid(b=True, which='minor')
ax3.grid(b=True, which='major')
ax3.grid(b=True, which='minor')

ax1.legend().set_title('Class A')
ax2.legend().set_title('Class B')
ax3.legend().set_title('Class C')

plt.style.use("classic")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]